# Visual C# Character Encoding Mix Up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encoding, utf-8

I've been working on a song Metadata program for a short while now, and have run in to what seems like quite a simple but challenging issue...

As the program reads in some pieces of data from songs, it may come across an usual symbol, such as **℗**. I noticed that some things happened that I didn't expect and so stepped through each line of my code individually. I noticed that said character was actually being read as "**â„—**". I tried this with another character,  Ü, to see what the result was, and this time I got "Ãœ".

I did a quick Google search which led me to this page:
http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

From this I would assume that my desired characters are actually being interpreted using the mentioned **Windows-1252** encoding, and not **UTF-8**?

I should add that to further investigate this, I tried writing the Windows-1252 versions into the Metadata using my program, and these came out in Windows itself as the correct ℗ and Ü characters... Can anybody tell me how to ensure that both read and write functions are done using UTF-8, and also tell me why this really happens if I was not correct. Thanks.

I am using C#.

Comment: What about trying to maintain the original byte stream even if your current machine or character display cannot show the characters the way you think they should be shown.  What I am suggesting is that it is a false error that your debug screen or application is displaying the wrong symbol but the actual byte stream is fine as is.  Is leaving it alone ok in your application situation?  I am curious what iTunes uses as its standard for metadata for encoding?

Comment: Strings and characters in Net Library are two bytes with a private property that indicates if the character is one or two bytes.  The Encoding method has the capability of setting the private property.  UTF8 encoding only handles the LSB of the two byte character.  Windows-1252 is shown on following page which also uses only LSB : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.  Now ascii character 0-127 are standard and 128-255 can vary.  1252 will decode 128-255 as shown on webpage while UTF8 will use different character when decoding for 128-255.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sql Surfer, I think I do understand what you're saying, although it is important that something needs to change, as, while the byte stream may be fine, if I add a GUI the wrong data is still read and written...

Comment: And jdweng, ah yes, I follow that! Although do you know of a solution to sort of override the decision? So that they're definitely encoded using UTF8.